# Адаптация приложения под различные экраны

Tags: storyboard, ios

Не знаю даже что гуглить, если честно. В сториборд контроллеры с размером под 4 дюйма, а как адаптировать под 3,5? Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: http://gyazo.com/e8233a8adb0ff74c43319ec369db17bc вот переключатель экранов. Если не то, так подробнее распишите, что вы хотите адаптировать.

Comment: ну, в каком то плане - да. Только получается, что я создаю интерфейс либо под 3.5, либо под 4 дюйма. Сейчас я решил свою проблему тем, что создал два сториборда, где абсолютно идентичные  интерфейсы за исключением того, что в одном под 3.5 дюйма, а в другом - под 4, и подгружаю их в зависимости от устройства. Но уверен, что есть более рациональные решения этого вопроса.

Comment: @svatorus, так в коде двигай/расставляй элементы так, как тебе нужно для определенного экран - всего то if -> else.
Зачем два сториборда - это извращение какое то))

Answer (score 2):

Вам скорее всего придется использовать [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html), создавая constraint и привязывая верхние и нижние элементы к границам экрана, тогда при различных экранах все само будет автоматом адаптироваться

Comment: да, спасибо, так и делаю)